# Email Extractor with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, email, extract

I used that code to extract emails from a webpage and

```html
from selenium import webdriver
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.airindia.in/contact-details.htm')

doc = driver.page_source

emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', doc)

for eamil in emails:
 print(email)
```

i Get that error

> ERROR:page_load_metrics_update_dispatcher.cc(208)] Invalid
>   first_meaningful_paint (unset) for time_to_interactive 10.226 s

what do you suggest me to do here

Comment: To me it looks like you ran into a Crome/chromedriver/selenium version incompatibility issue. Try using known-good combinations. See the chromedriver release notes for compatible versions here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt

Comment: @BoboDarph: please post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you ran into a Crome/chromedriver/selenium version incompatibility issue. Try using known-good combinations.

See the chromedriver release notes for compatible versions here:

[chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.tx)